# DragGestureDetector is not called

Tags: android, interface, swipe-gesture

Can Anyone tell me What is wrong in my code? i am using customadapter class and i set this adapter in cardstack when i am trying to swipe card, swipe is not working beacuse DragGestureDetector is not called.

i am using this library project
[wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack)

here is my code

```
 private void setupAnimation(){
    final View cardView = viewCollection.get(viewCollection.size()-1);


    mCardAnimator = new CardAnimator(viewCollection);


    mCardAnimator.initLayout();

  final  DragGestureDetector dd = new DragGestureDetector(mContext,new DragGestureDetector.DragListener(){

        @Override
        public  boolean onDragStart(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            Log.e("CardAnimator", "Dragstsrt");
            mCardAnimator.drag(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDragContinue(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                   float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            float x1 = e1.getRawX();
            float y1 = e1.getRawY();
            float x2 = e2.getRawX();
            float y2 = e2.getRawY();

            Log.e("CardAnimator", "Dragcontjnhue");
            //float distance = CardUtils.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            final int direction = CardUtils.direction(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            mCardAnimator.drag(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
            mEventListener.swipeContinue(direction, Math.abs(x2-x1),Math.abs(y2-y1));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public  boolean onDragEnd(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2) {
            //reverse(e1,e2);
            float x1 = e1.getRawX();
            float y1 = e1.getRawY();
            float x2 = e2.getRawX();
            float y2 = e2.getRawY();
            float distance = CardUtils.distance(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            final int direction = CardUtils.direction(x1,y1,x2,y2);

            boolean discard = mEventListener.swipeEnd(direction, distance);
            if(discard){

                Log.e("CardAnimator", "Dragend");
                mCardAnimator.discard(direction, new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                        mCardAnimator.initLayout();
                        mIndex++;
                        mEventListener.discarded(mIndex,direction);

                        //mIndex = mIndex%mAdapter.getCount();
                        loadLast();

                        viewCollection.get(0).setOnTouchListener(null);
                        viewCollection.get(viewCollection.size()-1)
                                .setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
                    }

                });
            }else{
                mCardAnimator.reverse(e1,e2);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTapUp() {
            mEventListener.topCardTapped();
            return true;
        }
    }
    );

    mOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MotionEvents";
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            dd.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    };
    cardView.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
}
```

Comment: how you add this lib?. While I try ,i cannot add this lib got error

Answer (score 0):

@Nimit : 
You should override **onDown()** and set return value true .you forget that method .Try like this and do let me know if any issues arise .

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                            float distanceY) {

          Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,"Action Scroll");
        if(mListener == null) return true;
        if( mStarted == false){
            mListener.onDragStart(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
            mStarted = true;
        }
        else{

            mListener.onDragContinue(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
        }
        mOriginalEvent = e1;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        return mListener.onTapUp();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent evt){
        mOriginalEvent = evt;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I make a sample project integrated with the lib. I succeed and working well for me.
But when I try to add a web view with HTML content, the swipe feature not work. If there a web view without HTML content or data, or outside of web view, we can able to get the swipe card feature. But I need to have a full-screen web view. so how the swipe functionality work with that, please help.